# How to change the data not available default message of data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to change to '**No data available in table**' message in empty data table with my **custom message**. How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created table with data-table plugin, you can use the following code to show the custom message.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No data available for selected date. Please select correct date."
    }
    } );
```

`#example` is id of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Change your custom message.

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable)

*This string is shown in preference to language.zeroRecords when the table is empty of data (regardless of filtering) - i.e. there are zero records in the table.
Note that this is an optional parameter. If it is not given, the value of language.zeroRecords will be used instead (either the default or given value).*
**Value: No data available in table**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "No data available in table"
    }
} )
```